# array not displaying the correct value

Tags: php

```
$data['results'] = $this->lawmodel->getuser($lastName);
$xp = array("lvl1" => 0, "lvl2" => 256, "lvl3" => 567);
foreach ($data['results'] as $row) {
   $my_xp = $row->points;   // the value is 300
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($xp); $i++) {
   if ($my_xp >= $xp[$i]) {
      $data['level'] = $i+1;
      break;
   }
   else {
      if (isset($xp[$i+1])) {
         if ($my_xp > $xp[$i] && $my_xp <= $xp[$i + 1]) {
            $data['next'] =  $xp[$i+1],;
            break;
         }
         else {
            $data['next'] =  $xp[$i],
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have a problem the output of `$data['level'] = $i+1` is always 1.. I want that it will output the key of an array that the value is equal or greater than `$my_xp`.

**Flow:**
If the points of the user is 300 it should be at lvl2.

Plss..i need help..im new in php..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array

```
$xp = array("lvl1" => 0, "lvl2" => 256, "lvl3" => 567);
```

has no integer keys

Try this code:

```
$data['results'] = $this->lawmodel->getuser($lastName);
$xp = array("lvl1" => 0, "lvl2" => 256, "lvl3" => 567);
$key_prefix = 'lvl';
foreach ($data['results'] as $row) {
   $my_xp = $row->points;   // the value is 300
}
$previous_xp = 0;
foreach ($xp as $lvl => $xp_value) {
if ($my_xp >= $xp_value) {
    $data['level'] = $lvl;
} else {
    if ($my_xp > $previous_xp && $my_xp <= $xp_value) {
        $data['next'] =  $xp_value;
    } else {
        $data['next'] =  $previous_xp;
    }
}
$previous_xp = $xp_value;
}
```

Comment: what u mean integer keys? @.@

Comment: Your array keys are strings = "lvl1", "lvl2", etc, but in your loop you are trying to access array keys 0, 1, 2, etc which don't exist. If possible, change your $xp array structure to something like this: `$xp = array(0, 256, 567);` That way $xp[0] and $xp[1] will point to the correct index in the array